# PHP Websocket undefined in Edge Browser

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, microsoft-edge, phpwebsocket

I developed a multiplayer card game and therefore used a websocket. To implement the websocket in php, I used [this library](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets)

I'v put it to my ubuntu server and the program works fine on Chrome Browser and in Firefox (The frontend is implemented using Javascript).
Using the Edge Browser, there is an error stating **"ReferenceError: WebSocket is undefined"**. But on the internet I have read that Edge should normally support websockets.

I already checked, whether the document mode is another IE version, but it is set to edge as well.
The exact version is 11.0.0600.18537.

The following is my code (althoug I don't think that is is a problem with it as it works in the other browsers)

```
 connectToSocket=function() {
    var host = "ws://[host]:9000/echobot"; 

    try
    {
       socket = new WebSocket(host);
       console.log('WebSocket - status ' + socket.readyState);
       ...
    }
    catch(ex){
        console.log('some exception : ' +ex);      
    }
```

Does anybody know what could be the issue with Edge?

Comment: your edge is miles out of date, just check that click the 3 dots click settings and scroll to the bottom mine on the latest version is running `Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0` however this is going to change soon as a new Release of windows 10 is due

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure you are actually writing `WebSocket` in your code? The error says that `Websocket` is not defined (with non-capitalized `s`).

The actual classname is `WebSocket` with a capital `S`.

Please confirm that the code you pasted as an example is really the same as the one you have in your application.

**EDIT**

After some further discussion in the comments I believe that WebSocket support might be [disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330736(v=vs.85).aspx#websocket) in your browser. WebSocket should be supported in your browser version (11.0.0600.18537) according to my own [experiment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHsf5.jpg) and [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=websocket).

Comment: But OP says it works fine except Edge, sure it would be nice to know from OP

Comment: Sorry, I edited the error in my question. Indeed, the error says "WebSocket" and the code is correct :-)

Comment: @user2550641 Are running the code on `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or connecting to  `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`? Try connecting to `ws://echo.websocket.org` in case it's a weird IE error and also perhaps testing in the browser the following address `http://www.websocket.org/echo.html`

Comment: Calling the url you mentioned (http://www.websocket.org/echo.html), the following error occurs:
"Uh-oh, the browser you're using doesn't have native support for WebSocket. That means you can't run this demo."
This obviously means, that my browser has no support for Websockets. But all over the web it is said, that this version of IE should support this...

Comment: @user2550641 Are you sure you're using a supported browser? I just tried in an IE11 VM with the exact version you specified (11.0.0600.18537) and it works: http://imgur.com/otHTKkO

Comment: there is also a field with "updateversions" which is: 11.0.38. Its a corporate browser, maybe there has been something disabled?

Comment: @user2550641 Possibly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330736(v=vs.85).aspx#websocket

Comment: Do you know, how to manage the feature controls? I looked in the installation folder of IE and in the internet options in the browser but there is no file that can be adapted or looks simliar to this

Comment: @user2550641 Sadly I don't have that knowledge. You should discuss that issue with your systems administrator.

Comment: Ok, seems to be the only possibility...I assume, that it has been disabled due to security reasons of the company...thank you for your support, at least, I can be sure now, that there is nothing to do on my side :-) 
Therefore I will accept your answer now.